# How to disable a wxTextCtrl Widget in wxWidgets C++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I'm writing a wxWidgets program in C++. It has several single line wxTextCtrls in it and I need to disable them so the user cannot enter text in them. Later, when a menu item is clicked, I want to enable them again. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `wxTextCtrl` is a subclass of `wxWindow`, it contains (probably overridden) virtual method `Enable` of `wxWindow`, documentation for which can be found [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a26d7329a9a753fa0445501f01f66c41e) and which controls whether the window is enabled for user input according to its boolean argument (which defaults to `true` - enable input). Also, there is a handy non-virtual `Disable` method, which is defined to be equivalent to `Enable(false)`.

You can use it like this to disable text control (assuming you save pointer to your `wxTextCtrl` instance in a `m_pTextCtrl` member of your window class):

```
m_pTextCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(...);
// ...
m_pTextCtrl->Disable();
```

and like this to enable it in your menu item event handler:

```
m_pTextCtrl->Enable();
```